# Why does 1 vector $\vec{v_1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is linearly independent imply that $\vec{v_1} \neq \vec{0}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why does 1 vector $\vec{v_1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is linearly independent imply that $\vec{v_1} \neq \vec{0}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what can happen if $\alpha \vec{v}=\vec{0}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the contrapositive statement.

If $\overrightarrow{v_1}=\overrightarrow{0}$ then $\overrightarrow{v_1}$ is not linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of independence of a family of vectors $v_1,\dots, v_n$ is:

> $v_1,\dots, v_n$ are linearly independent if for all $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such $\lambda_1 v_1+\dots +\lambda_n v_n =0$, we have $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_n=0$.

Instantiate for $n=1$: $v_1$ is linearly independent if, and only if, for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda v_1 =0$ implies $\lambda = 0$. Does that hold if $v_1=\vec{0}$?